# parallel_for function causes memory leaks (sometimes)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, optimization, memory-leaks, parallel-processing

I'm making a simple native MFC application and I'm using th Concurrency namespace to perform a simple parallel program (drawing a Mandelbrot set). The program is very very basic so far, clicking one button draws in parallel, the other draws in serial. The serial execution function is very basic and draws the right picture. As does the parallel execution function, however when running the debug build and exiting the program, the output tells me there is a memory leak.

Here's the code:

```
void CMandelbrotView::DrawSetParallel() {
// Get client area dimension which will be the image size
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(&rect);
//GetClientRect(pDC, &rect);
int imageHeight(rect.bottom);
int imageWidth(rect.right);

const double realMin(-2.1);             // Minimum real value
double imaginaryMin(-1.3);              // Minimum imaginary value
double imaginaryMax(+1.3);              // Maximum imaginary value
// Set maximum imaginary so axes are the same scale
double realMax(realMin+(imaginaryMax-imaginaryMin)*imageWidth/imageHeight);

// Get scale factors to convert pixel coordinates
double realScale((realMax-realMin)/(imageWidth-1));
double imaginaryScale((imaginaryMax-imaginaryMin)/(imageHeight-1));

CClientDC hdc(this);        // DC is for this view
OnPrepareDC(&hdc);          // Get origin adjusted

critical_section cs;            // Mutex for BitBlt() operation
parallel_for(0, imageHeight, [&](int y)         // Iterate parallel over image rows
{
    cs.lock();                                  // Lock for access to client DC
    // Create bitmap for one row of pixels in image
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);        // Get device context to draw pixels
    HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, imageWidth, 1);
    cs.unlock();                                // We are done with hdc here so unlock
    HGDIOBJ oldBmp = SelectObject(memDC, bmp);  // Select bitmap into DC

    double cReal(0.0), cImaginary(0.0);     // Stores c components
    double zReal(0.0), zImaginary(0.0);     // Stores z components

    zImaginary = cImaginary = imaginaryMax - y*imaginaryScale;
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)     // Iterate over pixels in a row
    {
        zReal = cReal = realMin + x*realScale;
        // Set current pixel color based on n
        SetPixel(memDC, x, 0, Color(IteratePoint(zReal, zImaginary, cReal, cImaginary)));
    }

    cs.lock();                              // Lock to write to hdc
    // Transfer pixel row to client area device context
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, y, imageWidth, 1, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    cs.unlock();                            // Release the lock

    SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
    DeleteObject(bmp);                      // Delete bmp
    DeleteDC(memDC);                        // and our working DC
});}
```

The code for parallel execution is different from the serial execution code that it creates separate rows of the Mandelbrot image in parallel, and uses a critical section lock to make sure the threads don't fight over the same device context handle.

Now the reason I said there is memory leak reported sometimes is because running the release build does not cause a memory leak to be reported. Also, when running parallel execution function multiple times I don't really notice more memory being being used up, I have 6GB of RAM in case anyone is wondering.
As far as the performance goes, my quad-core machine does actually present a roughly 4x increase in calculation+drawing speed from serial execution.
I've also seen similar questions asks on the msdn website, but not of much use, because this may be a VS bug. Anyway, I'd like a parallel programmer's opinion.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down where the supposed leak is coming from? It's probably not from any of the GDI code (GDI resource leaks are rarely reported as memory leaks) so you should try removing all of that, leaving just your IteratePoint loop being called in parallel. If that still leaks, look at what it is doing (which we cannot see from the code sample provided).

Comment: @Leo Actually, I did remove everything from the parallel_for function, it's seems that just having the parallel_for statement (supposedly) causes a memory leak when executing the debug build. I'm starting to suspect it may be the compiler, debugger, or a small defect in the installation of VS10. I'd still like some clarification.

Comment: You should edit the question to remove all of the irrelevant code then; that way people are more likely to be able to see what might be going wrong. Also, are you sure it's not just being misreported? Memory leak tools are notorious for false-positives. Which tool is reporting it and what exactly is it reporting?

Comment: @Leo Sorry about the poorly worded question, it's the output tab on Visual Studio that indicates a memory leak, showing a long list on memory location when exiting the program. I wasn't aware that memory leak tools had these kind of problems. Here's a sample of the output: The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x55ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{5840} normal block at 0x00F816A8, 8 bytes long.

Comment: Are you sure that the leak is in this part of the code? Here, the memory is allocated only for 2 things: memDc & bmp and I see that you are calling the appropriate function to clean up the resources. Could you please confirm once that the leak is in this part only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is documented in the [fix-list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/12/20/visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta-feedback.aspx) for VS2010 SP1.  The feedback article [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/575506).  Beware that SP1 is still in beta right now so avoid installing it on important production machines.  Download [is here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=207130).

Comment: Thanks, that's a much more specific answer. However, my memories of using Windows Vista have made nervous of using software that isn't fully prepared, so I'll just wait to install it with Windows Update instead of downloading the beta. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What I would say is, write a quick deleter function for unique_ptr and use that for your resources. The only way I could see this code leaking is by throwing, but I don't see any places that throw. Once you remove that vulnerability, I don't see any leaks at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that the leak occurs 'some times' and not always. However, there is no branching in your code (specifically: branching with memory allocations) so either it should always cause the leak or never cause the leak. Moreover, as already mentioned in my comment, Memory is being allocated only at two place for `memDc and bmp` and you are properly cleaning up the resources for both the variables.

In simple words, I want to say that there is no leak in the above code :)
If there is actually a leak in your application, that would be in some other code path probably.

Comment: @Vikram.exe To answer your earlier comment, I literally removed all the objects and from the parallel_for loop and a memory leak was still being reported, but removing the paralel_for function completely doesn't cause a memory leak to be reported. I'm not actually sure what you mean by a leak in the application, the application only has a basic MFC view with two buttons added that do nothing more than execute a function. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If no leak is reported after removing paralel_for function, then you can safely ignore my comment :). However I still don't believe there is a leak here.

Comment: @Vikram.exe So in your opinion, it is just a false-positive?

Comment: Could be. If its on *NIX, I could debug this by hooking malloc/new function with my own function and track the allocated memory (using LD_PRELOAD with dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"..") (args...)). I don't know how to do the same thing on windows. Try something on this track if you have any idea on this for windows.

Comment: @Vikram.exe I decided to take your advice the easy way, I ran the function a bunch of times, and have not observed an increase. I'm 99.9% sure it's just a false-positive, but I'm going to take a look at other opinions, including tracking the memory and using unique pointer templates, before I come to a conclusion.

Comment: If that's the case, you can replace 99.9% with 100% in your comment :)

Comment: There is no leak here, this is a known issue in the reporting with ConcRT and MFC and was fixed in SP1 I believe.